# Javascript for loop problems

Tags: javascript, for-loop

So I have the following code which i basically just a JSON string I am using eval to convert to an object. Now, this object has an array of elements that gets displayed to the screen via a for loop:

```
function DisplayListing(str)
{
    var obj = eval("(" + str + ")");
    var div = document.getElementById('Response');
    for(i=0; i<obj.files.length; i++)
    {
        div.innerHTML += '<span id="listing' + i + '" class="displayNone"><img src="' + obj.files[i].icon + '"/>' + obj.files[i].name + '</span><br />';   
    }   
}
```

This works just fine. However, what I want it to do is wait a set interval of time before it continues to the next element. I want to it basically call a function with a timeout, so each element fades onto the screen individually. All attempts so far on cause the last element to execute a function. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I Know! It's an internal project. No outside risks.

Comment: Thanks for the warning though.

Comment: Eval is not always a bad idea, if the source is trusted and precautions are taken eval can be a nice and quick tool. But rarely can you trust a source so I would recommend using a json parser from [json.org](http://www.json.org/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/SfKNc/

```
var obj = {files: [1, 2, 3]}; // sample object - use JSON.parse by the way
var div = document.getElementById('Response');
for(var i=0; i<obj.files.length; i++) { // use var!
    setTimeout((function(i) {
        return function() { // i changes, so create a new function in which i does not change
            div.innerHTML += 
                '<span id="listing' + i + 
                '" class="displayNone">' + i + 
                '</span><br />';
        };
    })(i), i * 1000); // set timeout to 1000 ms for first item, 2000 for second etc.
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, however I am getting a syntax error: unexpected token around `return function() {`

Comment: @pimvdb: does this need to install N timers (N = obj.files.length) ?

Comment: @jiri: It currently does, yes.

Answer (score 0):

you have manually create a sleep function something like the below:

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

or you create an empty function and use the setTimeout on it

```
  function sleep()
    {
    setTimeout(Func1, 3000);
    }

    Func1(){}
```

http://www.phpied.com/sleep-in-javascript/

Comment: Note that the infinite for loop causes the browser to hang, and might not work if looping `1e7` times finishes earlier (which is certainly possible as of today).

Comment: it was just to show an idea the source is the web site showed at the bottom.I personally prefer the second sleep function